# Count the number of files matching the naming pattern

Tags: bash, awk

In the workdir there are N files that ends with *after_MD.pdb.[number], where number is 1,2,3 ... N

```
ls -t *after_MD.pdb.*
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.29  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.14
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.28  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.13
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.27  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.12
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.26  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.11
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.25  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.10
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.24  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.9
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.23  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.8
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.22  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.7
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.21  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.6
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.20  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.5
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.19  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.4
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.18  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.3
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.17  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.2
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.16  6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.1
6nax_apo_POPC_60A_after_MD.pdb.15
```

I need to count these files and store its total number as separate bash variable e.g. using awk it should be something like:

```
number_of_files="$(awk 'do_something' *after_MD.pdb.*)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be solved in many ways. I will list some of the most elegant ones that come to my mind.

```
count=$(printf '%s\n' *after_MD.pdb.* | wc -l) 
#or
count=$(shopt -s nullglob; files=(*after_MD.pdb.*); echo ${#files[@]})
#or
count=$(du -a *after_MD.pdb.* | wc -l)
#or
count=$(file *after_MD.pdb.* | wc -l)
#or
count=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*after_MD.pdb.*" | wc -l)
```

**It is better not to use `ls` according to [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) article.**

Comment: why this could be better compared to the $(ls *after_MD.pdb.* | wc -l) ?

Comment: @JamesStarlight check here to find out Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Great, thank you very much !

Comment: The `echo ... | wc -w` would still report a wrong number if the file names contained whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

If the file names don't contain newlines, you can use `wc -l` to count the lines:

```
number_of_files=$(ls *after_MD.pdb.* | wc -l)
```

Or, you can loop over them and count them:

```
number_of_files=0
for file in *after_MD.pdb.* ; do
    (( ++number_of_files ))
done
```

Comment: Thank you very elegant ! What would be the difference with : file_count=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*after_MD.pdb.*" | wc -l)

Comment: Find would exclude directories even if their names matched the pattern. `-iname` is case insensitive, so it might include AFTER_md, too. If the iname argument doesn't contain any wildcards, it won't match any of the files you're interested in. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' *after_MD.pdb.*` would be more robust than `ls ...`, e.g. if the number of files exceeded ARG_MAX.

Answer (score 2):

Turning matched entries into a string whose length is the matches count.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob # Pevents returning the pattern when no match is found

# Prints 1 character of each matched entries into the s variable
printf -v s %.1s *after_MD.pdb.*

# The number of matched entries is the length of the s variable
printf 'There are %d files matching the *after_MD.pdb.* pattern\n' "${#s}"
```

Alternatively, storing matched entries into an array, allow to just query the array length, and even allow working with each stored entry.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob # Pevents returning the pattern when no match is found

# Store matched entries into an array
entries=( *after_MD.pdb.* )

# The number of matched entries is the length of the array
printf 'There are %d files matching the *after_MD.pdb.* pattern\n' "${#entries[@]}"
```

Comment: Dear Léa, both of your solutions are incorrect. I would appreciate it if you could correct them. In both solutions, even if it doesn't find any matches, it still displays `1`!, which you need to correct with `shopt -s nullglob` or other ways.

Comment: @Freeman added. Thank you for reminder